# Not able to exit telnet session from sh shell command prompt

Tags: linux, sh, telnet, busybox

I am using "BusyBox v1.22.1 (2015-02-09 13:48:39 IST) built-in shell (ash)
" and I have ran one script in background mode which was running in continuous while loop with some delay.

Than, I have typed "exit" command to come out from that session from which i have started one script.

but, I could not came out from that session.

Does any one has idea about this type issue or is there any configuration required in busybox to solve this issue?

Comment: It would be helpful if you said exactly what is necessary to reproduce the problem and also just as exactly what happened. My guess is that you need to kill the background process before you can log out, using either `kill` or by pulling it into the foreground and then using control-C.

Comment: But, I want to exit telnet session by executing "exit" command while script is running in background mode.

Comment: You want to keep the started script running in the background after your session has ended? Then Joachim's answer is the way to go! Note that output redirection is shell-specific, so check your shell's documentation if his approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the child process still have connections to the shell, for the input and output.

If you really want to run the child process independently from the parent shell that spawned it, then there are two things you need to do: The first is to use the [`nohup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nohup.1.html) command to start the program, the second is to redirect the standard input, output, and error streams.

So do something like e.g.

```
$ nohup ./your_program >/dev/null </dev/null 2>&1 &
```

The redirection operators work like this:

- `>/dev/null` redirects standard output to the `/dev/null` special file, which accepts all and any output and just discards it
- `</dev/null` redirects standard input from the same special file, which causes all reads to give end-of-file
- `2>&1` makes file descriptor 2 (standard error) be the same as file descriptor 1 (standard output), which means all output to standard error will be using standard output and automatically be redirected to `/dev/null`